# Type of AtomicReference

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following:

```
AtomicReference < String> tmpRef_nullStr = new AtomicReference < String>(null);
```

and

```
AtomicReference < String> tmpRef_helloStr = new AtomicReference < String>("hello");
```

Is there a way to check the type of these AtomicReferences so that in both cases returns a type of String?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you clarify?

Comment: At runtime; these both have a type of `AtomicReference` not String.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to check the type of the object that the AtomicReference holds.

Comment: Are you also trying to find the class type of null variables? That might just be NullPointerExceptions, as described by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712881/type-of-reference-type-with-value-null

Comment: No. If I have AtomicReference < String> ref_str = new AtomicReference < String>(null) then if I ask ref_str.get() == null will be true. I'm wondering if there is a way to ask for the type of the object (not the value of the object) that ref_str holds, which in this case the test should return a type of String.

Comment: How could it hold anything **but** string? Are you using raw or wildcard types?